# Web Application host header

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

What's the host header when create a new web application ? is it important ? when I should set it ? is it require a special configuration ?

Please help Thanks

Ali

Comment: Why -1 :( what this mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the host header to run different web applications on the same port. Usually you want to define several WebApps to run on port 80, and without host header, that's not possible.

So use the host header if you want to run more than one webapp on the same port.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but when I should use the same port for multiple web application should give me example and how to configure it ?

Comment: From the New Web Application Page, you have the option to add host header. Use myhostname for the web app http:;//myhostname and contoso.com for the web app http://contoso.com

Comment: when I should set host header ? is it useful , should you give me scenario when I can decide to use multiple web application with the same port , I am sorry i am new :)

Comment: When you have searchcenter.company.com and intranet.company.com and qualityportal.company.com and marketing.company.com and so on :)

Comment: Thanks a lot , it's clear now :) , last thing please should share link that explain how to configure host header in details

Comment: This one is good :) http://thuansoldier.net/?p=1323

Comment: How I can thank you ? many thanks :)

Comment: We're all here to learn! Enjoy and good luck :)